# C# Timer ticks speeding up, probably due to incorrect usage

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, timer

*(Note: I know there's a related Q+A, but it relates to the timer ending, whereas mine is to do with ticks)*

This code is used to animate a rectangle moving between 2 points. At the moment, the first movement is perfect, but each time after that the animation becomes significantly faster and faster each time it is called.

I'm thinking it's due to a misunderstanding on my part on how to call a rectangle movement on each tick.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This section starts the timer:

```
        if (floorNo == 2)
        {
            timerDown.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_LiftDown);
            timerDown.Interval = 10;
            timerDown.Enabled = true;
            timerDown.Start();
        }
```

This code is called on each tick (right?):

```
    void timer_LiftDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rectangle1.Location = new Point(192, rectangle1.Location.Y + 2);
        if (rectangle1.Location.Y >= 196)
        {
            timerDown.Stop();
        }
    }
```

I've cut out some unrelated code (e.g updating textboxes with current state, changing floorNo variable etc).

Thank you.

Comment: It's hard to tell from what you posted, my first guess is that you're subscribing to the `Tick` event repeatedly, causing the event handler to run n+1 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of subscribing and unsubscribing to the event each time, I would suggest setting up the timer once, and then just calling start/stop on it.

```
//Somewhere in a load event...
timerDown.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_LiftDown);
timerDown.Interval = 10;
timerDown.Enabled = true;

//More code...

if (floorNo == 2)
{
    timerDown.Start();
}

//More code...

void timer_LiftDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rectangle1.Location = new Point(192, rectangle1.Location.Y + 2);
    if (rectangle1.Location.Y >= 196)
    {
        timerDown.Stop();
    }
}
```

That way, you only have to initialize the timer and set the interval once, and can start/stop at will.

Comment: I tried that just now. I have timerDown + timerUp functions. Moving one of the .Tick/Interval/Enabled sections into the load event fixed that function. However, moving both into it caused the elevator to flicker, and fail to move at all. Any idea how to get both playing nicely? *EDIT*: I got it working. Thanks buddy.

Comment: Reading up on `Timer`, it looks as though setting `Enabled` to true also starts the timer, so what's probably happening is that they both get set to enabled and then start and conflict. (Which is the flicker you see.) Calling `Start` enables the timer so you don't need to explicitly state that. Remove the 2 lines that set enabled to true for each timer, I'm thinking that should fix it.

Answer (score 3):

You are adding an event handler, but not removing it.  So each time you call the animation, another handler is added.  As such each tick is handled twice and causes the animation to speed up.

You need to add

```
timerDown.Tick -= new EventHandler(Timer_LiftDown);
```

at some point in your code.  Unfortunately, from the snippet you have provided it is not clear where this can be safely added.

Comment: Should this be added once the animation has finished, and the timer has been stopped?

Comment: Yes ideally. You need to remove every handler you have added. Or redeclare the timer.